# Get data from child component on click on parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

new to React and my problem is following.

Parent component has Button and with map function, it renders a lot  components which are a number of inputs where user can change data leave it.

```
import { Form } from 'formik';
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const Wrapper : React.FC = ( props: any) => {

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const { formData, setValues } = useFormDataValues();
   
     return (
      <Form>
          <div>
            <button>
                Save Data
            </button> 
            { 
              props.cells.map( (cell: any,ind: number) => (

              <div key={ind} >
                  <Pattern props={{ "cell": cell }} />                              
              </div>

             }
             ))
          </div>             
    </Form>)
```

Pattern component:

```
const Pattern = (props:  PatternProps) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const { formData, setValues } = useFormDataValues();

      return (
        <>
        {Object.keys(props).map( (c: string) => (
            <div >
            {
             <input name={c}  ref={register} defaultValue={props[c]} />
            }
            </div>

          ))}
          </>
          )
```

On click in parents component Button i should get all of input data (data from input component) from childern component (Pattern). I tried with react-hooks-forms and Formik to combine the getting, but couldn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no reason for `Pattern` use `formik` hooks, you already consume it at `Wrapper`. remove this hooks from `Pattern` and pass down as props from `Wrapper`. This way Wrapper will a have more centralized form.

```
<Pattern data={{ "cell": cell }} // I suggest to rename here to something more semantic rather than 'props'
         formHandlers={{ register, handleSubmit, errors, formData, setValues }} 
         // pass down necessary handlers
         />
```

at Pattern:

```
// update PatternProps accordingly
const Pattern = (props:  PatternProps) => {
  const { formHandlers, data } = props

  return (
    <>
    {Object.keys(data).map( (c: string) => (
        <div key={c}> // pass a unique key here
          <input name={c}  ref={formHandlers.register} defaultValue={data[c]} />
        </div>

      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi This is great and it works but there is other concern : 
after submiting i only get the last input values. How can i get the every value with ref={formHandlers.register} in an array ?  Is the right way to use context variable and fill it in there as an array ?

EDIT: also there is no formData as param in the useForm() i used formState (if that is what you ment)

Comment: Here i have a sandbox

 of the detailded question, you can see that i pass through a json data in forms, but i can't still get all of written data into the json on Save button from the parrent.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-goldwasser-sw65z?file=/src/components/Pattern.jsx

Comment: if you pass `name` to input as `name={\`${data.guid}.${name}\`}` you will get each form piece associated to its id.

Comment: thank you very much ! i ll need to learn a lot about react !

Comment: you are welcome :) little by little you will get there, cheers!!